# how to calculate bundle product price from array of custom selection through parameter(post data)?

Tags: arrays, magento, parameters

the data got from post is.

```
[productid] => 3
[product_type] => bundle
[bundle_option] => Array
    (
        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1
                [1] => 2
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => 3
                [1] => 4
            )

    )

[qty] => 1
```

how to calculate the bundle price for my selections. The magento core funtions are more preferable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by own method, not sure its acceptable or not.

```
$bundle_option = Mage::app ()->getRequest ()->getParam('bundle_option');
$bundle_option_array = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $bundle_option);
$price =  Mage::Helper('airhotels/bundle')->getBundlePrice($productid,$bundle_option_array);
```

my helper file is

```
public function getBundlePrice($productId,$bundle_option_array) {
$product = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();
$product->load($productId);
$price=0;
$selectionCollection = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getSelectionsCollection($product->getTypeInstance(true)->getOptionsIds($product), $product);
foreach($selectionCollection as $option) 
{
    if (in_array($option->getSelectionId(), $bundle_option_array)){
        $price += $option->price; 
    }
}
return $price;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code:

```
public function getDisplayPrice($product) {
    if($product->getFinalPrice()) {
        return $product->getFormatedPrice();
    } else if ($product->getTypeId() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_BUNDLE) {
        $optionCol= $product->getTypeInstance(true)
                            ->getOptionsCollection($product);
        $selectionCol= $product->getTypeInstance(true)
                               ->getSelectionsCollection(
            $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getOptionsIds($product),
            $product
        );
        $optionCol->appendSelections($selectionCol);
        $price = $product->getPrice();

        foreach ($optionCol as $option) {
            if($option->required) {
                $selections = $option->getSelections();
                $minPrice = min(array_map(function ($s) {
                                return $s->price;
                            }, $selections));
                if($product->getSpecialPrice() > 0) {
                    $minPrice *= $product->getSpecialPrice()/100;
                }

                $price += round($minPrice,2);
            }  
        }
        return Mage::app()->getStore()->formatPrice($price);
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you..... but this code gets all default bundle options from the product....my custom selection of child products comes  from POST.. how to add my selections array in code....